# Visual Studio "Structure Guideline" for Flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-2019

I used Visual Studio Version 1.38.1 as the editor for My Flutter Dev. How to add "structure guideline" like attachment below?

[See Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5YQ7.png)

Thank for advance

Comment: Visual Studio Code ?

Comment: Yes, its VS code

Comment: flutter plugin already manage that

Comment: No, I didn't get "bold line" like attachment above, but some kind like this https://repository-images.githubusercontent.com/129891790/83afaa00-676b-11e9-87b5-766e9d430642